# Angularjs error when move function outside button click event

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-click

I have a problem with angularjs.

When I replace my code

```
<button ng-click="pickProject(project)" <img static-src="icons/im/open.png"/></button>
```

by {{pickProject(project)}}, it cannot work.

Please help me.

Comment: Well, if it doesn't work when you replace it, don't replace it...?

Answer (score 0):

ng-click takes reference as a method. When button is clicked, the method will be called, {{}} enclosed syntax is for value not for method reference.
So, {{pickProject(project)}} can not be used.

Also {pickProject(project)} is incorrect, the correct syntax is {{data/function with return value}}, you need to use {{ at the beginning and }} as ending, not one { at the beginning and }} at the ending.